Pyomo warmstart does not work with GLPK and CBC
I am trying to warmstart a MIP using Pyomo and a free solver like GLPK or CBC.
Following the documentation it is enough to specify warmstart=True in the following code:
mod.y[2,1] = 1
mod.r[2,2] = 1
mod.y[3,1] = 1
mod.r[3,2] = 1
mod.y[4,5] = 1
mod.l[4,4] = 1
mod.y[5,5] = 1
mod.l[5,4] = 1
mod.y[6,1] = 1
mod.r[6,2] = 1
opt.solve(mod,tee=True,warmstart=True)

In this case, I assign some values to the variables and I want to solve the problem with this warmstart.
When I do this I got the following error both with CBC and GLPK:
key 'warmstart' not defined for ConfigDict '' and implicit (undefined) keys are not allowed

I looked for some solutions on the web. I found another way to specify this:
opt.options['warmstart'] = 2

This work only for CBC, but I do not understand if the solver effectively use the warmstart or not.
The idea is to try to improve the computation giving to the model a very good instance generated with an heuristic. Ideally should be perfect if the solve start with this solution and try to improve it a bit. I know that a warm start solution could not improve the computation, but I aspect it starts from here.

"I do not understand if the solver effectively use the warmstart or not" can you include the log of the optimization in the question?

tee=True should show information but I do not see nothing. I also tried with opt.solve(mod, logfile='path/to/logfile.log') but the log is almost empty

I tried the simple following example and it works well.
m = ConcreteModel()

# decision variables
m.x1 = Var(domain=NonNegativeIntegers, name= "x1", bounds=(0, 10))
m.x2 = Var(domain=NonNegativeIntegers, name= "x2", bounds=(0, 10))

# objective function
m.OBJ = Objective(expr = (3*m.x1 + 2*m.x2), sense = maximize)

# constraints
m.C1 = Constraint(expr= m.x1   +  m.x2 <=  9)
m.C2 = Constraint(expr= 3*m.x1 +  m.x2 <= 18)
m.C3 = Constraint(expr= m.x1           <=  7)
m.C4 = Constraint(expr=           m.x2 <=  6)

# MIP start
m.x1 = 4
m.x2 = 5

# solving process
SolverFactory('cbc').solve(m, tee= True, warmstart=True).write()

The output shows the solver uses the warm-start:
opening mipstart file /tmp/tmpjk8u13f_.cbc.soln.
MIPStart values read for 2 variables.

A sample notebook to run and test the model.

Hi, thanks for the comment, I cut and pasted the code. I got the same error: key 'warmstart' not defined for ConfigDict '' and implicit (undefined) keys are not allowed. Maybe is my installation of cbc? I simply linked the executable. It works, in the sense that is able to solve problems.

@user2695795, I am unsure if I understand your last comment. Could you fix the issue or not?

No, using your code  I got the same error:

key 'warmstart' not defined for ConfigDict '' and implicit (undefined) keys are not allowed

@user2695795, I just added a sample notebook.

@user2695795 you should also check that you have the Same versions of pyomo and cbc.

The colab notebook works, but if I cut and paste and run on my laptop I got the same error again. My pyomo version is 6.7.3 while the cbc version is 2.10.10. I am running the code on Windows
